# Tesseract identifies a 0 as a Q

Tags: optimization, tiff, tesseract, identification

I am using Tesseract OCR for getting an exclusively numeric string in a PDF file.
The PDF contains : 66600O3377.pdf
but Tesseract recognizes : 66600Q3377.pdf

The input is a TIFF file, the quality is good enough (see the screenshot).

Is there a way to improve the Tesseract accuracy ? I could always change Q for a 0 but I'm afraid of further unexpected mistakes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in [Tesseract FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_recognize_only_digits):

Run a tesseract command like this to only permit digits in input image:

```
tesseract imagename outputbase digits
```

Comment: my full command should be : tesseract temp.tiff output digits -psm 4 > /dev/null 2>&1 ?

Comment: The options `-l lang` and `-psm N` must occur **before** any configfile (e.g. `digits`). In other words, command line should be: `tesseract temp.tiff output -psm 4 digits >/dev/null 2>&1`